# Magento some products image not show

Tags: magento-1.9

In my store some products' images are not showing. I have set base image , thumbnail correctly.
Also I deleted cache, but it did not work for me. So I changed media folder permission to 777 but no luck.
Below is my store front end and back end screenshot.
any idea why this is happening.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you checked `Exclude` box in backend. please uncheck it , so that you can able to see the image in frontend. we uploaded some images, for tempararily we want to hide those images, so we will select exclude checkbox. later if you want to display those images, you can uncheck the box

Comment: i removed it.but not working.

Comment: did you save the product after you uncheck that box.

Comment: yes but it not working. any idea

Comment: in single product.page image show but as secondary image

Comment: are you using any extension ?

Comment: no. that happen for only few images.

Comment: did you moved site from one domain to another ?

Comment: yes.i moved it from one domain to another

Comment: i am not sure, than may be thats the reason, when you migrate images path will create some problem, means some alphabets in the path will display  as `small` you need to change to `caps` compare your product images paths whcih are working and not working. if you have path like `media/q/image.jpg` you may need to rename something like `media/Q/image.jpg`

Comment: or [this](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=WIJ7V9qWMsaL8Qe94ITQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=magento+images+not+showing+after+migration&start=10) may works for you.

Comment: i don't know anything doesn't worked for me.